# error on cross compile gdbserver

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, gdb, gdbserver

I want to use gdb to debug on arm-Linux development board. I get error when compiling gdbserver.

Host: Ubuntu 11 32bit
Target: arm-linux-gcc (gcc version 4.4.3)

```
root@mickeyvm:/home/mickey/gdb-7.4# ./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux

make
```

I get this error message:

```
configure: error: no termcap library found
```

From what I have searched in Google. The compiler cannot get ncurses library.

```
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
```

I follow suggested solution to install libncurses5-dev, but the problem still exist.
The libncurses5 really exists in my Linux.

```
root@mickeyvm:/home/mickey# dpkg -l | grep curse
ii  libcurses-perl                                  1.28-1                                     Curses interface for Perl
ii  libghc6-hscurses-dev                            1.3.0.2-3build3                            ncurses bindings for Haskell - development files for GHC6
ii  libncurses5                                     5.7+20101128-1                             shared libraries for terminal handling
ii  libncurses5-dev                                 5.7+20101128-1                             developer's libraries for ncurses
ii  libncursesw5                                    5.7+20101128-1                             shared libraries for terminal handling (wide character support)
ii  libncursesw5-dev                                5.7+20101128-1                             developer's libraries for ncursesw
ii  mtr-tiny                                        0.80-1                                     Full screen ncurses traceroute tool
ii  ncurses-base                                    5.7+20101128-1                             basic terminal type definitions
ii  ncurses-bin                                     5.7+20101128-1                             terminal-related programs and man pages
ii  ncurses-term                                    5.7+20101128-1                             additional terminal type definitions
```

Please help and point out what I missed. Thank you very much

Comment: Try `apt-get install libtinfo-dev` and then re-try the `./configure` and `make` steps.

Comment: You need to cross build all the needed libraries for the ARM target and setup the dependent lib path for target arm env accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> Host: Ubuntu 11 32bit

32-bit what? Presumably your host is i686-linux-gnu, and not sparc-linux-gnu.

> ./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux

With above command you are attempting to build GDB that will run on `arm-linux` and debug `arm-linux` binaries, i.e. you are configuring a *native* GDB for arm-linux (but building it on i686-linux). Such native GDB can't use host libraries (for obvious reasons).

But it looks like you want a cross-gdb, not a native one. In that case, try

```
./configure --build=i686-linux --host=i686-linux --target=arm-linux
```

Reading [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/explaining-build-host-target-509739/) might help.

Comment: As it looks to me, he wants the native ARM gdb to run directly on board. And still it doesn't answer the question.